# How to convert/cast IQueryable<AnonymousType> to IQueriable<Strong Typed Object> with lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, casting, lambda, iqueryable

Here is what i would like to achive:

```
 int id = 1;
        var db = new Project.Models.Context();
        var query1 = db.Users.Where(t => t.id == id);
        //here is where the problem starts
        IQueryable<Project.Models.test> test = query1.Join(db.Table2,
                    users => users.id,
                    table2 => table2.userId,
                    (users, table2) => new
                    {
                        users.UserName,
                        table2.SomeValue
                    });
```

I have tried so far:

-cast query1 to

```
(IQueryable<Project.Models.test>)query1
```

-add the storgly typed name at the key word new:

```
 (users, table2) => new IQueryable<Project.Models.test>) ...

 (users, table2) => new Project.Models.test ...
```

-naming colums
    (users, table2) => new
    {
         ColumnName1 = users.UserName,
         ColumnName2 = table2.SomeValue
     });

-combinations of above

I allso understand that there is a way to solve this using normal sql expressons using:

```
 select new Project.Models.test 
        {
            ColumnName1 = users.UserName,
            ColumnName2 = table2.SomeValue
        }
```

but I would like to write this with lambda expressions, if possible.

I am a first time poster and a long time reader, hopefully everything is written correctly and clearly.

ps: I allso took the liberty of simplifing variable names and the join query.

edit:

For the sake of compleaton:
saving the query in a anonymous variable joinedTable and then making a "insert into" statement works.

```
IQueryable<Project.Models.test> tst = from a in joinedTable
                                      select new Project.Models.test
                                      {
                                          UserName = a.UserName,
                                          SomeValue = a.SomeValue
                                      };
```

So a sub questin would be if it is possible to write the above statement with lambda expressions.

Comment: that way is the only way. there is no way to cast.

Comment: I'm not with you - both the Join projections anonymous -  `(users, table2) => new {...}`, and the strongly typed `(users, table2) => new Project.Models.test {...}` both use lambdas. The latter doesn't need to be cast as it is already of the given type? (Even if the anon class has exactly the same shape as a Strong POCO, it can't be cast directly to it AFAIK)

Comment: What does not work when you try your option `(users, table2) => new Project.Models.test(){
            ColumnName1 = users.UserName,
            ColumnName2 = table2.SomeValue
        }`? What error do you get? And is Project.Models.test an sql datatype or a custom class that has no corresponding equivalent on the sql side? In the later case, it may be impossible to use it in an sql join.

Comment: It works now! I have misstyped one of the column names. Now i can have all my queris in lambda form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is:

```
int id = 1;
    var db = new Project.Models.Context();
    var query1 = db.Users.Where(t => t.id == id);
    //here is where the problem starts
    IQueryable<Project.Models.test> test = query1.Join(db.Table2,
                users => users.id,
                table2 => table2.userId,
                (users, table2) => new Project.Models.test()
                {
                    columName1 = users.UserName,
                    columName2 = table2.SomeValue
                });
```

ColumnNames have to correspond to properties in new Project.Models.test().

Props go to HugoRune for making me reexamin my code. I would allso like to point out that Jaap Elgersma anwser allso solves the problem, but not in lambda notation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
    IQueryable<Project.Models.test> query =
        from u in db.Users
        join t in db.Table2 on u.id equals t.userId
        where u.id == id
        select new Project.Models.test  
                {
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    SomeValue = t.SomeValue
                };
```

Comment: Yes in a way, but i would liks to write this experssion in lambda notation, if possibe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible. You could do

```
result.AsEnumerable().Select(anonymous => new Typed { Property = anonymous.Property));
```

But that's extremely ugly. I'd also try to look at the generated code using dotPeek.